# Vuex lazy commit / buffer state changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with a specific use-case
where my application can call `store.commit` 3 times or more
in a second and those making the application lag or freeze the browser.
So what I though was, can I buffer state changes
before actually commit the changes and update view.

For the first question that I'm not clear about are,
does vue update it's view on every state changes or not?

For example I have the following code

```
state = {
  // Here i was using object instead of array of object
  // so I can get into my target object instead of
  // finding my target object first
  rooms: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Room 1' },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Room 2' },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Room 3' }
  }
}
mutations: {
  setRoom(state, payload) {
    const id = payload.id
    const oldData = state.rooms[id]
    const newData = Object.assign({}, oldData, payload.room)

    Vue.set(state.rooms, id, newData)
  }
}
actions: {
  updateRoom(store, { roomId, patch }) {
    store.commit('setRoom', { id: roomId, room: patch })
  }
}
// And later
store.dispatch('updateRoom', { roomId: 1, patch: { name: 'Room 11' } })
store.dispatch('updateRoom', { roomId: 2, patch: { name: 'Room 22' } })
store.dispatch('updateRoom', { roomId: 3, patch: { name: 'Room 33' } })

// Those store.dispatch come from a websocket and possible to have
// custom `patch` data
```

For the second question, if the above code update 3 times.
Is there a way to buffer the changes or update the view
only once?

So instead of doing change state 3 times
first changes

```
{
  rooms: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Room 11' },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Room 2' },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Room 3' }
  }
}
```

second changes

```
{
  rooms: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Room 11' },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Room 22' },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Room 3' }
  }
}
```

third changes

```
{
  rooms: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Room 11' }
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Room 22' },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Room 33' }
  }
}
```

Can it become only one changes happend? Like

```
{
  rooms: {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Room 11' }
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Room 22' },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Room 33' }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue:

> Whenever a data change is observed, (Vue) will open a queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event loop. If the same watcher is triggered multiple times, it will be pushed into the queue only once. (...) Then, in the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and performs the actual (already de-duped) work.

So... don't worry about it, Vue is already taking care of it.

And why don't you use an array? Assuming that all room IDs are in a secuential order starting with 1, you can instantly access `Room 1`in `rooms[0]`, `Room 2` in `rooms[1]` and so on, and accesing an array by index will be faster than accessing an object by key.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I just know about vue queue state update, thanks for pointing out.

And for state being object instead of array, in my case roomId are timestamp-like number, and it was not in sequential order, so yeah for getting room data, I will need to search array index first then update the data by that index.

Comment: Oh cool, yeah, it makes sense then. And you're using Vue.set and Object.assign too, so it will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have rooms as an array of objects you can commit at once, if it's feasible.

```
state = {
  rooms: [
     { id: 1, name: 'Room 1' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Room 2' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Room 3' }
  ]
}
mutations: {
  setRooms(state, payload) {
    state.rooms = payload
  }
```

Other is to limit how the updateRoom is being invoked, would need to know how that is being called.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Updating my question on why the state being an object instead of array, and `setRoom` mutation on why it should only updating 1 room only